# Remove multiple spaces in ls -l output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I need to display the filesize and the filename. Like this:

```
4.0K Desktop
```

I'm extracting these two fields using cut from the ls -l output:

```
ls -lhS | cut -d' ' -f5,9
```

Due to multiple spaces in the `ls -l` output, I'm getting a few erroneous outputs, like:

```
4.0K 19:54
4.0K 19:55
 6
 18:39
 31
 25
```

How should I fix this?

I need to accomplish this task using pipes only and no bash scripting ( output could be multiple pipes ) and preferably no sed, awk.

If no alternative to sed or awk is available- use of sed is OK.

Comment: why not use `du -sh *`?

Comment: Have you tried giving it to `tr -s ' '` and then parsing?

Comment: @spasic : you should put it as answer.

Comment: @PS. the specifics of question seems like a exercise problem.. waiting for OP to clarify

Comment: @spasic : Its meant for a demo to a class

Comment: so, why not use `awk` which by default splits a line on white-space? or use another demo (with made up input file).. unless you want you specifically show why this problem statement is one of the reason to avoid parsing `ls` and use other appropriate programs

Comment: A very simple `ls -lhS | awk '{print $5 " " $9}'` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use translate character command before using cut.

```
ls -lhS | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 5,9
```

Answer (score 2):

You [`can avoid parsing ls output`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and use the `stat` command which comes as part of `GNU coreutils` in bash for detailed file information.

```
 # -c  --format=FORMAT
 #         use the specified FORMAT instead of the default; output a newline after each use of FORMAT

 # %n     File name
 # %s     Total size, in bytes

 stat -c '%s %n' *
```

Comment: Hey, I got this `stat: cannot stat `%n': No such file or directory
stat: cannot stat `*': No such file or directory`

Comment: @PS. Use `stat -c '%s %n' *`

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just submit to awk:

```
$ ls -lhS | awk '$0=$5 OFS $9'
```

ie. replace whole record `$0` with fields `$5` and `$9` separated by output field separator `OFS`.